# Ubuntu VTK for Python compiled from source

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, vtk

I compiled VTK 7.0 (6.3 has the same effect) over cmake with following params:

```
-LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH:PATH="" -CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="/usr/local" -VTK_ENABLE_VTKPYTHON:BOOL="1" -Module_vtkPython:BOOL="1" - -VTK_Group_Qt:BOOL="1" -CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH="/usr/bin/objcopy" -VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND:STRING="OpenGL2" -VTK_INSTALL_PYTHON_MODULE_DIR:PATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" -DVTK_EGL_DEVICE_INDEX:STRING="0" -VTK_WRAP_PYTHON:BOOL="1" -Module_vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL:BOOL="1"
```

Now i can find the binary "vtkpython" at /usr/local/bin .

Good news:

I am allowed to enter python shell with the command "vtkpython" out of this directory (/usr/local/bin) with all the needed vtk bindings.

```
markovich@markovich-desktop:~$ cd /usr/local/bin/
markovich@markovich-desktop:/usr/local/bin$ vtkpython
vtk version 7.0.0
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
>>> vtk
<module 'vtk' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtk/__init__.py'>
>>>
```

Thats a bit irritating because i am expecting to run my default python environement and the vtk bindings are available.

so the bad news:

if I type `python` in my shell or `vtkpython` from another location on my system the shell says "no modulen named vtk found" on calling `import vtk` .

```
markovich@markovich-desktop:~$ vtkpython 
vtk version 7.0.0
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named vtk
>>>
```

Question 1: Maybe I missed something in the make configuration ?
Question 2: If I take the actual status (which is somehow working): Is it possible integrate the "vtkpython" bindings in my default python environment? If I am not totally wrong. The binding is correctly loaded out of my python2.7 path like you can see in the terminal:

```
<module 'vtk' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtk/__init__.py'>
```

So how can I add this module to be loaded in Python environment?

Answer (score 0):

Since loading `vtkpython` clearly shows that you have the module available *somewhere* on your system, you should be able to add the location of the vtk module to your PYTHONPATH variable.

Find where the vtk module is installed (try `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, you should see a `/vtk` folder). If you're unsure, you could try to find it in `vtkpython` with

```
import vtk
import imp
imp.find_module('vtk')
```

You can check what paths are stored in PYTHONPATH by entering in terminal:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

(In my install, it was empty by default.)

Then you can add the vtk folder location to your PYTHONPATH in terminal:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Check if vtk is availabe:

```
$ python
>>> import vtk
```

If it works, you can add the `export...` line above into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` (as appropriate per your distro installation) to permanently load the option in PYTHONPATH.